# Is there a better alternative to Zipkin dependency graph for springboot applications?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, zipkin, dataflow-diagram

I am trying to find out if there exists a tool that can show realtime traffic flow for springboot + springcloud microservices for my architecture. While searching for such tool, I pondered upon Zipkin's dependency graph. Is it good enough? Or are there any better alternatives to show realtime flow of traffic?

Furthermore, I am seeking an opensource project more than a proprietary solution but I'd be open for either suggestions.

Our architecture is built upon springboot+springcloud hosted in AWS and OCI and using K8s as well.

Any advice/suggestion would be quite helpful.

Attached is zipkin's dependency which is somewhat similar to what I am trying to find out:

[image: zipkin's dependency graph]

Looking forward to it.
Kind regards.

Comment: Maybe netflix's vizceral what you are looking for.
https://github.com/Netflix/vizceral

also datadog has this capability, but it isnt free

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend Jaeger.

Jaeger is open source software for tracing transactions between distributed services. It’s used for monitoring and troubleshooting complex Microservices environments. Now ServiceMesh is becoming more and more popular at Microservice field, jaeger has become one of the recommended project to work with ServiceMesh.

Jaeger architecture: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.28/architecture/

Install Jaeger on Kubernetes: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.28/operator/

Jaeger with SpringBoot: https://medium.com/xebia-engineering/jaeger-integration-with-spring-boot-application-3c6ec4a96a6f